# Count rows from 2 columns when sum between 2 cells is non-zero in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count the rows when sum between cells of C and D columns is non-zero (i.e. greater than 0). As shown in image, I want to calculate value using formula which should be 3.
I tried `countif` and `countifs` formula, but not giving expected result.

Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try:

```
=SUM(N(MMULT(C2:D5,{1,1})>0))
```

Comment: Getting Value error when copy-paste formula.

Comment: What is your Excel's locale settings (language)? Maybe you need to change `{1,1}` to `{1;1}` @SSG

Comment: I need to extend formula to large range as # of rows filled could be different. Looks like this cannons be accommodated in formula, can we?

Comment: Why not @SSG? Worked fine for me.

Comment: I get value error when Range is `C2:D18000`. But last filled row in sheet is 181.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Excel 365 you can use:

`=SUM(--(BYROW(C2:D5,LAMBDA(r,SUM(r )))>0))`

`BYROW` creates kind of a helper column summing the value per row - and then checks if > 0

Comment: Cannot commit formula when added in cell. Excel thinks it's not a formula.

Comment: then you are not on Excel 365

Comment: I've MS 365 Enterprise account.

Comment: What is your excel language?

Comment: It's an English.

Comment: hmm - then you need to check the channel of your excel version - I think it has to be at least "semi annual"

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution with a helper column:
[image]

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to add/use any extra column.